# Migration from prototype.js

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, internet-explorer-10

prototype.js is extending native objects and rarely is updated. We use it in a large application and migration to another JavaScript library is so expensive for us. You think how long we can continue using it considering IE 10 and new EMCAScrip?

Comment: I don't think new browsers with better standard support should be a problem for you.

Comment: If something in Prototype 1.7.1 isn't working in IE10 - please file a ticket. I'm using Prototype-based app in IE8-10 without problems.

Comment: The most recent version was released Aug 2012 with a complete overhaul of the DOM utility and compability with EMCAScript5 [see here](http://prototypejs.org/2012/08/08/prototype-1-7-1/)